# Who's got higher priority CPU or DMA controller?

Tags: embedded

Let's assume i have to refresh OLED screen pretty often using I2C so i want to take load from CPU and let the DMA transfer the data for me. After commanding DMA, CPU is executing next instructions untill it reaches point where it needs bus(let's say to communicate with SPI perhiperal). What happens then? Does DMA yields or the CPU waits until DMA finishes it's task?

Architecture: Cortex-M4 or M0+

Comment: what chips are you referring to?

Comment: and what did the vendor say when you asked?

Comment: Kinetis microcontrollers from NXP, their datasheet doesn't refer to it

Comment: the arm cores have nothing to do with it, dma logic if any is from the chip vendor, and your question would then be per chip per vendor. (and only the vendor knows or public docs).  too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used Kinetis family but I think I can see the answer in their reference manuals.
Let's take [K12 Sub-Family Reference Manual](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/reference-manual/K12P121M50SF4RM.pdf)

On the page 69 there is info about **Crossbar-Light Switch Configuration** ([Here](http://cache.freescale.com/files/training/doc/ftf/2014/FTF-IND-F0212.pdf) presentation describing it):

[image]

In the same document on the page 308:

[image]

Default mode of this switch is fixed priority (p. 301) - **it means in case you presented CPU needs to wait**.